# Does it make sense to upgrade the graphics driver when running Ubuntu on virtualbox?

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox, intel-graphics

I am using Nvidia graphics card. I run Ubuntu 16 on virtualbox. Host OS is windows 10. Does it make sense to upgrade the graphics driver in my Ubuntu image running on virtualbox? My CPU also support integrated Intel Graphics.

Comment: Virtualbox is not using your real graphic card for the virtual operating system - it is simulating a virtual one. So i doubt it makes sense to try to install some additional driver for that virtual graphic card, as long as it works in general.

Comment: It would make sense if you would use a virtualization technique where you could pass-through a real graphic card (1 of 2 physically installed) to the virtual os. Then you would for sure have to install a matching driver for that card inside your virtual linux. Virtualbox does not support that as far as i know. More on that topic here: http://superuser.com/questions/945740/passthrough-graphics-card-to-virtualbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do not install/run proprietary graphics drivers in your guest Ubuntu.

By installing the [guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) you will install a custom virtualbox graphics driver that will make use of your host graphics adapter including 3D-acceleration if enabled.

It does however make sense to upgrade your **host** graphics drivers because bugs there may also affect the virtual graphics drivers in the guest.